# All if statements rendered when using dompdf

Tags: html, conditional-statements, dompdf, ob-start

I'm using dompdf for a results page. Statements that did not meet the condition still leave a placeholder/blank space in the PDF. I'm using ob_start to grab the HTML and pass to dompdf output -- is it saving more than just the output to the buffer? Viewing source, the statements which were not executed are not visible.

```
<?php 

ob_start(); 

?>

<html>
  <ul>
    <?php if($quizData['q2_o5'] == 1){ ?>
       <li>Lipsum</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et egestas sapien. Curabitur facilisis suscipit est ac auctor. Praesent et tellus malesuada arcu tincidunt condimentum. Donec id risus est.</li>
        </ul>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php if($quizData['q2_o6'] == 1){ ?>
       <li>Lipsum</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et egestas sapien. Curabitur facilisis suscipit est ac auctor. Praesent et tellus malesuada arcu tincidunt condimentum. Donec id risus est.</li>
        </ul>
   <?php } ?>
   </ul>
</html>

<?php

    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_flush();
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    $file_to_save = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/completed/output.pdf';
    file_put_contents($file_to_save, $output); 

?>
```

Comment: Add a sample of the conditional statements. It's possible that the structure of your code still leaves the spacing even if the actual text is not present.

Comment: Thanks, I've added samples

Comment: So where is the placeholder? The UL itself will still be there and could take up space depending on the styling. Otherwise ... ? Can you add a screen shot of the PDF?

Comment: It turns out it was the CSS. I removed it and formatting was just as it should be. Since I can't change the current CSS I'll have to push the output to a string rather than in the buffer. Once I go through and find which style was causing the issue, I will post.